# Saving data on Android for data visualization

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm creating an app where I'm going to be storing data that the user enters. Let's say for instance it's someone weight. I have created an SQLite database that is able to store this information. However, I want the user to be able to update the value if the weight changes, but I don't want to lose the previous data. Would I have to create a separate database to store this past information? Or is there a more effective approach? Thanks for your time.

Comment: This is most basic SQL. You should take a tutorial

Comment: You need to create a database that stores all the values, past and present. It's a single database, but could be multiple tables.